# How to reduce visible part (or mask) of mapbox style layer?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have hexagonal tileset added as a layer to mapbox style though mapbox studio.

Trying to find possibility to reduce layer visible area. For example to show only 100m radius (or square with side equal to 100m) area around map center (current point marker).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a bounding box and use `fitBounds` method of the map, for example:

```
const boundingBox = [
   [minX,  minY],
   [maxX, maxY]
];

map.fitBounds(boundingBox);
```

More about `fitBounds` and other examples you can find [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/).

For creating bounding box you can use [Turf.js](http://turfjs.org/) library.

This code uses [buffer](http://turfjs.org/docs/#buffer) and [bbox](http://turfjs.org/docs/#bbox) methods to create bounding box with 100m side and given point in the center:

```
const pointBuffer = turf.buffer(point /* - your point GeoJSON */, 0.1, 'kilometers');
const boundingBox = turf.bbox(pointBuffer);
```